# SQL - Check correct answer for multiple-choice question

Tags: sql

I am working on a multi-choices questions form. A contributor will write a question with 3 to 4 possible answers. There is always only one correct answer. What would be the most efficient way to check if a selected answer if the answer? I can also change the value stored in the correct_answer column.

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE `questions` (
  `question_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `contributor_id` int NOT NULL,
  `question_text` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `answer_a` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `answer_b` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `answer_c` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `answer_d` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `correct_answer` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`question_id`)
)
```

```
def add_contributor():
    name = request.form.get('contrib_name')
    question = request.form.get('question')
    answer_a = request.form.get('answer_a')
    answer_b = request.form.get('answer_b')
    answer_c = request.form.get('answer_c')
    correct_answer = request.form.get('correct_answer')
    
    sql_1 = "INSERT INTO contributors (name) VALUES (%s)"
    sql_2 = "SELECT contributor_id from contributors WHERE name=(%s)"
    sql_3 = "INSERT INTO questions (contributor_id, question_text, answer_a, answer_b, answer_c, correct_answer) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
        
        
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql_1, name)
    cursor.fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    
    cursor_2 = conn.cursor()
    cursor_2.execute(sql_2, name)
    contrib_val = cursor_2.fetchall()
    contrib_id = contrib_val[0][0]

    cursor_3 = conn.cursor()
    cursor_3.execute(sql_3, (contrib_id,question, answer_a, answer_b, answer_c, correct_answer))    
    cursor_3.fetchall()
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: Are you storing their submitted answer somewhere?  You would need that to compare.

Comment: No I haven't. I will have multiple users. Do you think I should create a new table for that? I was actually thinking to also split the `questions` table into 2 smaller tables: `questions`and `answers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM questions
    WHERE question_id = yourQuestionId 
    AND correct_answer = yourAnswer)
THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END
```

However if you are not using a stateless application (such as a webpage) then you would be better off loading the question once and checking the answer in the program code.

Comment: Thanks I am actually using flask on the back-end, i updated my question! thanks